# how to create DTO in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, oop

[OOD table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duSKN.jpg)

Hi I'm wondering how would you write the dto of what i underlined. would it be something like this

```
    public Student EnrolledStudents
    {
        get; private set;
    }
```

Comment: Because the name of the property is in plural, I would expect it to be a `List<Student>`?

Answer (score 2):

Just Create a class that includes the field of what you want in DTO. and Then Initialize the object simply in your buisness logic class/in repository where your data is being fetched.

Answer (score -1):

A DTO is really just a stupid class, that can hold data. Therefore you can create a class with the property you posted, although based on the picture you posted, i would say that maybe it's a list?

```
public class MyDto {
    public List<Student> EnrolledStudents {get; private set;}
}
```